# How to make ActiveMQ detect duplicate message from message publisher (Idempotent producer)

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, idempotent

Does ActiveMQ support Idempotent producer? I know Camel has an idempotent consumer pattern to detect and handle duplicate messages, but I'm wondering if this can be prevented at the source (producer).

Here is a little back ground. I have applications that are horizontally  scaled accessing same database. There is one particular table that maintains status of a particular process. These horizontal applications should be able to read the status and invoke another process, however only one of them should be able to invoke it. This application periodically polls the data base and posts a message to a messaging broker, once the required condition is met. But I want one of the load balancing application should be able to post the message.

One crude approach I'm thinking is...

On Machine 1:

1. Read the database for checking if the necessary condition is met.
2. Before posting message to the broker, write a record to another status table with a unique key that identifies the process and commits. If this operation fails due to unique key constraint violation, it means process on another machine succeeded in posting the message.
3. Post the message to the broker
4. If the message posting is failed, for some reason, perform delete operation on the status table based on the unique key/ primary key.

The same operation can be performed by same application running on machine 2 , 3, 4 etc.

Below is one pitfall I quickly notice with this approach.

Assuming that Machine 1 is able to complete step 2 but failed performing step 3 and continues with step 4. Meanwhile Machine 2, when it failed at step 2, will move on with out attempting to read the status again and post the message.

To address this, I need to put retry on step 3, until the message is successfully posted to broker.

Another option is to use https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/idempotentConsumer-eip.html pattern. But this is essentially a filter at consumer side. Though this will serve my purpose, is there a similar approach out of box available on message publishing side.

I wonder, if this approach is even correct or any better alternative approach, or any existing libraries that can be used to perform locking kind of mechanism across JVM either local or remote.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm yet to implement the suggestion. Artemis is not an option, as it is not yet approved in our project.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why it isn't approved? Which version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help others who have this same question in the future. If not, please clarify what's lacking. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what version of ActiveMQ you're using (i.e. [ActiveMQ 5.x](http://activemq.apache.org/components/classic) or [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis)) so I'll try to address this issue for both.

ActiveMQ 5.x doesn't have any built-in support for detecting duplicates sent from clients. However, you could potentially implement this feature using a [broker plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/interceptors). The only challenge I see here is configuring, managing, and monitoring the cache of duplicate IDs.

ActiveMQ Artemis *does* have built in support for detecting duplicates sent from clients. You can [read more about duplicate detection in the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/duplicate-detection.html). Since the broker supports this behavior natively it provides clean configuration, management, and monitoring.

In either case you'll need to set a special header on each message with "a unique key that identifies the process" just like you would for your potential database solution. Furthermore, using the broker as the duplicate detector is *much* simpler overall.

If you're currently using ActiveMQ 5.x but want to move to ActiveMQ Artemis in order to use the duplicate detection feature you don't necessarily need to update your clients as ActiveMQ Artemis fully supports the OpenWire protocol used by 5.x clients. You should just be able to point them to the new instance of ActiveMQ Artemis and have everything work.

Comment: Hi boss. What are those enigmatic properties `checkForDuplicates`, `auditDepth` and `auditMaximumProducerNumber` in https://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri.html ? They can lead us to wonder there's some duplication handling...

Comment: Those configuration properties apply to *consumers*, not producers which is what the original question was asking about. The OpenWire JMS client shipped with ActiveMQ Classic supports duplicate detection, but since this functionality is only implemented in the client it provides no benefit for clients of other protocols (e.g. AMQP, STOMP).