# How to solve the queue multi-consuming concurrency problem?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, queue, jms

Our program is using Queue.
Multiple consumers are processing messages.

Consumers do the following:

1. Receive **on** or **off** status message from the Queue.
2. Get the latest status from the repository.
3. Compare the state of the repository and the state received from the message.
4. If the on/off status is different, update the data. (At this time, other related data are also updated.)

Assuming that this process is handled by multiple consumers, the following problems are expected.

1. Producer sends messages 1: on, 2: off, and 3: on.
2. Consumer A receives message #1 and stores message #1 in the storage because there is no latest data.
3. Consumer A receives message #2.
4. At this time, *consumer B* receives message #3 at the same time.
5. Consumers A and B read the latest data from the storage at the same time (message 1).
6. Consumer B finishes processing first. Don't update the repository as the on/off state is unchanged.(1: on, 3: on)
7. Then consumer A finishes the processing. The on/off state has changed, so it processes and saves the work. (1: on, 2: off)

In normal case, the latest data remaining in the DB should be **on**.
(This is because the message was sent in the order of on -> off -> on.)
However, according to the above scenario, off remains the latest data.

Is there any good way to solve this problem?
For reference, the queue we use is using **AWS Amazon MQ** and the storage is using **AWS dynamoDB**. And using Spring Boot.

Comment: Is this a high concurrency system -> meaning you probably can't cut down the consumers? If yes then you'd need some sort of locking mechanism, i.e. only a single consumer can update a specific row, other consumers need to wait in order until the lock is freed

Comment: Does this mean DB lock?

Comment: Well, you could introduce timestamps for your messages and only update the DB if the current message has a more recent timestamp. This could be checked in the update query, e.g. something like "... SET state = x WHERE timestamp < y". If consumer 1 updates the timestamp to 3 before consumer 2 can execute its query the update should not happen because `3 < 2`  is false.

Comment: Since the state change is important, I cannot skip step 2.

Comment: Read [this](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-preserve-order-of-messages.html) to see how to guarantee delivery order in ActiveMQ (probably go for the JMSXGroupID). You probably want [JmsTemplate](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/) since you are working with Spring. For non-trivial cases you probably also need message idempotency. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62506865/how-to-make-activemq-detect-duplicate-message-from-message-publisher-idempotent) is interesting to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that you need to consume these "status" messages *in order*, but you're using concurrent consumers which leads to race-conditions and out-of-order message processing. In short, your basic architecture using concurrent consumers is causing this problem.

You could possibly work up some kind of solution in the database with timestamps as suggested in the comments, but that would be extra work for the clients and extra data stored in the database that isn't strictly necessary.

The simplest way to solve the problem is to just **consume the messages serially** rather than concurrently. There are a handful of different ways to do this, e.g.:

- Define just 1 consumer for the queue with the "status" messages.
- Use ActiveMQ's "[exclusive consumer](https://activemq.apache.org/exclusive-consumer)" feature to ensure that only one consumer receives messages.
- Use [message groups](https://activemq.apache.org/message-groups) to group all the "status" messages together to ensure they are processed serially (i.e. in order).